# how to make a trigger like primary key constraint?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i need to define a trigger which i want to apply on a column of table. The trigger should restrict the user to input duplicate and not null values. Or you can say, i need to know the logic of primary key.

Comment: You can simply define the column to be `unique` and `not null` !

Comment: yes i know i can, but i want to learn, how primary key is made(it is a trigger of course). i want to make my own trigger which should work same as primary key.

Comment: Why do you think a primary key is implemented as a trigger under the hood? Constraints and triggers are quite different things.

Answer (score 3):

Just because you seem intent on seeing this fail, and not to take anything away from APC's points, this appears to work at first glance as long as it's a `before` trigger:

```
create table t42 (id number);

create trigger trig42
before insert or update on t42
for each row
declare
  c number;
begin
  if :new.id is null then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'ID is null');    
  end if;
  select count(*) into c from t42 where id = :new.id;
  if c > 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'ID is not unique');
  end if;
end;
/
```

It compiles and if you insert data you get the behaviour you seem to want:

```
insert into t42 values (1);

1 rows inserted.

insert into t42 values (1);

Error starting at line 20 in command:
insert into t42 values (1)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-20002: ID is not unique
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.TRIG42", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STACKOVERFLOW.TRIG42'

insert into t42 values (null);

Error starting at line 22 in command:
insert into t42 values (null)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-20001: ID is null
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.TRIG42", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STACKOVERFLOW.TRIG42'

select * from t42;

        ID
----------
         1
```

Which seems to do what you want. But not if you have more than one session. I haven't committed in this session; in another session I can do:

```
insert into t42 values (1);

1 row created.

select * from t42;

        ID
----------
         1

1 row selected.
```

Hmm, that's strange. Well, maybe it's deferred... let's commit them both:

```
commit;

select * from t42;
        ID
----------
         1
         1

2 rows selected.
```

Oops.  Once session can't see another session's uncommitted data, so this will never work.

Also, the mutating table problem exhibits itself when we insert multiple rows in a single statement:

```
SQL> insert into t42 select level+1 from dual connect by level <= 5; 
insert into t42 select level+1 from dual connect by level <= 5
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table STACKOVERFLOW.T42 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.TRIG42", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STACKOVERFLOW.TRIG42'


SQL>
```

Double oops.

Even with an `after` trigger and a package to work around the mutating table issue, you'd still have this problem (I think), unless you lock the whole table for every insert or update. As APC said the constraint is implemented deep in the bowels of the database, not at this level.

> is it not possible to define a trigger, which checks the value before
>   insertion that it should not be null and unique as well?

Not when you have more than one session, no. And even within one session, unless you have an index on the column the performance won't scale as the `count(*)` will get progressively slower. And if you do have an index, well, why not make it a unique index in the first place?

Finally, from the [trigger design guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#i1006211):

> Do not create triggers that duplicate database features.
>
> For example, do not create a trigger to reject invalid data if you can
>   do the same with constraints (see "[How Triggers and Constraints
>   Differ"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHCEBAE)).

Comment: I'm surprised this trigger compiled and executed (in particular, the "executed" part). Given that it appears to be a row trigger which is doing a SELECT on the table upon which it's defined I expected it to get a "mutating table" error.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @Bob - I was surprised too, but I avoid triggers so much I wasn't sure if that only affects after triggers - don't think so. Maybe the table being empty makes a difference - but it wouldn't know that yet? If I remember I'll try to investigate next week.

Comment: thank you so much Alex. you have explained very well and in detail.
thanks a lot

Comment: @BobJarvis - the mutating table error kicks in when inserting several rows.  Try `insert into t42 select level+1 from dual connect by level <= 5; ` and see what happens.  Clue: ORA-04091

Comment: @APC - clearly you have far more experience with this, I've been too successful avoiding it! Thanks, I didn't know you only got this with `insert ... select`. Any number of individual `insert ... values` seems to be fine, but even a single-row `insert into t42 select 1 from dual` on an empty table gets the ORA-04091. As I said before to Bob, I was surprised I got as far as I did, I started off expecting to demonstrate the mutating table error immediately, and got sidetracked. Seems to have dissuaded the OP from persuing this approach, anyway, which was the main point...

Comment: I try to avoid triggers as much as possible.  But it helps to know *why* they're such a bad idea :D

Comment: @APC - absolutely. Thanks for the edit, that does clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

> " i want to learn, how primary key is made(it is a trigger of course)"

There is no "of course" about it.  A constraint is not a trigger.  It is an internal process which uses an index and a lot of low level activity to enforce relational constraints in a reliable and efficient manner.

If you want to learn the rules are quite straightforward: not null, uniqueness, serialization. So just try to implement a primary key in triggers.   You'll find you can't (spoiler alert!) because of the "mutating table" problem.  And if you don't understand what that means, well there's a good topic to read about.

---

> there is a question "is it not possible to define a trigger, which
>   checks the value before insertion that it should not be null and
>   unique as well? "

The answer to that question is, No.  Well, you could code a trigger-based implementation but like other "mutating table" workarounds it would require a package and AFTER statement triggers (so technically not before insertion).

But seriously, what would be the point?  You won't learn anything about how primary keys actually work.  And mutating tables almost always point to a poor data model, and that would certainly be the case here.

Comment: thank you APC. it is clear to me that it is not a trigger. yes there will be a mutating condition. 
there is a question "is it not possible to define a trigger, which checks the value before insertion that it should not be null and unique as well? "

Answer (score 1):

Primary key is not a trigger. It is a key, because it identifies the whole row, that's why it should be unique (and implicitly not null). It is "primary", because it is the candidate key that is most appropriate - by your decision - to be the main reference key for your table. You can add it as `ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD CONSTRAINT PK_your_table_name PRIMARY KEY (your_key_column)`.

If you do not want to add a primary key like that (which is a bad idea), but want to add a unique index to that table: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_IX_your_table_your_column ON your_table_name (unique_column_name)`.
The `NOT NULL` constraint should be put on the column.

Comment: Yes, just the primary key is the candidate key that is most appropriate  (by your decision) to be the main reference key for your table. I should've put this in my answer, sorry.

Comment: you are going totally a wrong way!!!!
i am not asking, how to define keys and their use.

Comment: you are not getting my question..... or i am not good to explain.
i just need to know is "define a trigger on a column of a table which should act like a primary key. it is not to define a constraint. "

Comment: I see. Then you'll need a trigger for the insert and update actions, but I see that Alex Poole already wrote down the solution. Sorry for the misunderstanding...