# Compication while creating Primary Key like logic in Oracle PLSQL Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

According to the requirement we are facing a unique situation.We would like to create something of a virtual primary key on a table only for a specific submitter id. Note: Submitter id is one of the columns in the table.

We decided to use triggers to achieve this goal however for insert it works fine, but when checking for update it gives the following error:
[ORA-04091: table XYZ is mutating, trigger/function may not see it]

A sample example for understanding the workflow:

Table Structure (Sequence,Submitter_id,Country,Description)

Unique Primary Key: Sequence

If Submitter_id = 'SYSTEM' then we need something of a virtual primary key on Country as well.

Current Code for BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE trigger on table XYZ which is giving error during update:

```
If (:NEW.Submitter_Id = 'SYSTEM') Then
    BEGIN
        SELECT  count(1) INTO counterVariable
         FROM XYZ
         WHERE Country = :NEW.Country
         And Submitter_Id = 'SYSTEM';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20005, 'Sample Error');
    END;

    If (counterVariable != 0)
    Then
       raise_application_error(-20005, 'Primary Key Violation error');
    End If;

End If;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609844/how-to-make-a-trigger-like-primary-key-constraint  Similar question but without any concrete solution. Looking for a work around to solve my problem which doesn't involve primary key constraint or unique index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do it with a trigger. I would just create a functional unique index.

```
create unique index xyz_unq on xyz(decode(submitter_id, 'SYSTEM', country));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its a great idea however in the real scenario there are 4 columns  instead of 1(country).

Comment: I guess it still can be done with an index. Just use a CASE statement instead of DECODE.

Comment: Oh, you said, "instead of country..." Then it's even more simple. Create a functional index on four columns using four DECODE's.

Comment: It works for my real scenario as well. create unique index xyz_unq on xyz(decode(submitter_id, 'SYSTEM', country),decode(submitter_id, 'SYSTEM', B),decode(submitter_id, 'SYSTEM', C));

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful :)